# Difference between "heap size" and "SOC"

Tags: arcgis-server, administration

About **ArcGIS Server Administrator Directory** and concerning the **Server Machine Properties**, what are the differences between :

- App server maximum heap size (in MB)
- SOC maximum heap size (in MB)

Current Version: 10.5.0

Platform: Windows Server 2012 R2-amd64-6.3

Comment: Those parameters seem to be related to the maximum file size that can be sent to the GIS Server. But I don't understand how it could be tested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heap size is a property and SOC is a component of the ArcGIS Server. You can't really compare them.

Both the App Server (**Application Server**) and the SOC (**ArcSOC process**) are components of the ArcGIS Server. (Ie. these map to actual *.exe processes you'd see in your task manager)

The Heap size setting (*in MB)* property is generally only changed when you're uploading larger files or making requests that require a large amount of memory to process. Typically the SOC heap size is set to 64mb and is sufficient. The AppServer heap size is generally set to 256mb by default.

A few examples of when you may need to modify the setting:

- [Changing heap size for a map service that fails due to an extremely larger query](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011736)
- [Changing heap size in geoprocessing to upload larger filers](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/10.3/publish-services/linux/geoprocessing-service-settings-advanced.htm)